# invalid use of incomplete type 'PGconn {aka struct pg_conn}'

Tags: c++, c, oop

I have two classes, Main class and a connection class as:

**Conn.cpp:**

```
#include "conn.h"
#include <postgresql/libpq-fe.h>

Conn::getConnection()
{
        connStr = "dbname=test user=postgres password=Home hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5432";
        PGconn* conn;
        conn = PQconnectdb(connStr);
        if(PQstatus(conn) != CONNECTION_OK)
              {
                cout << "Connection Failed.";
                PQfinish(conn);
              }
        else
              {
                cout << "Connection Successful.";
              }
        return conn;

}
```

**conn.h**

```
#ifndef CONN_H
#define CONN_H
#include <postgresql/libpq-fe.h>
class Conn
{
public:
    const char *connStr;
    Conn();
    PGconn getConnection();
    void closeConn(PGconn *);
};
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <postgresql/libpq-fe.h>
#include "conn.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    PGconn *connection = NULL;
    Conn *connObj;
    connection = connObj->getConnection();

return 0;
}
```

**error: invalid use of incomplete type 'PGconn {aka struct pg_conn}'**

**error: forward declaration of 'PGconn {aka struct pg_conn}'**

Any help?

Comment: Your `conn.cpp` looks totally wrong. You have the definition of `Conn::getConnection()` nested inside itself?

Comment: Yes you are right, but i made it clear and errors are unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your conn.cpp, `conn::getConnection()` has no return type. From your code, I guess you need to return a pointer to PGconn:

conn.h

```
class Conn
{
public:
    const char *connStr;
    Conn();
    PGconn* getConnection();
          ^^ return pointer instead of return by value
    void closeConn(PGconn *);
};
```

conn.cpp

```
PGconn* Conn::getConnection()
^^^^^^ // return PGconn pointer
{
   connStr = "dbname=test user=postgres password=Home hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5432";

   PGconn* conn = NULL;
   conn = PQconnectdb(connStr);
   if(PQstatus(conn) != CONNECTION_OK)
   {
       cout << "Connection Failed.";
       PQfinish(conn);
   }
    else
    {
      cout << "Connection Successful.";
    }
    return conn;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your `conn.h`, you should define `getConnection` as returning a `PGconn *`, not `PGconn`. `PGconn` is an opaque type (your code should not know anything about it besides the name), so you can't return it or use it by value.

Comment: It's so weird that you tell it a specific type that works elsewhere in the code and the compiler can't figure out what you are actually trying to return. PGconn isn't an opaque type elsewhere!

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
PGconn getConnection();
```

Since `PGConn` is an incomplete type, you cannot *define* a function that returns it by value, only a pointer to it.

Comment: Wrong, you declare a return or pass by value of an incomplete type. The problem is the definition of the method, not the declaration.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore You are gonna have to back that up, because I can't see how a copy c'tor can be called for a forward declaration.

Comment: Since it's just a declaration, nothing is called.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, Fair enough.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, Although I would like to point out that declaring is also not passing. So you still can't *pass* an incomplete type by value :P

Comment: Yes, true, I'm sure you knew this, just thought the answer could be clearer ;)